# Call setup code of superclass

Tags: objective-c

My class A is initialised like that:

```
- (instancetype)init // designated initializer
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [self setup]; // just sets some properties
    }

    return self;
}
```

I have the following class B which subclasses A:

```
- (instancetype)init 
{
    self = [super init]; // calls the initializer of A and SHOULD call the setup code of A but it does not

    if (self) {
        [self setup]; // just sets some properties for B
    }

    return self;
}
```

## **My Problem:**

B should call A's setup method but it does not due to the dynamic typing of Objective-C. Instead B calls its setup code **twice**.

How can I resolve this problem (besides renaming the methods) or even better **ARE THERE ANY BETTER APPROACHES?**

---

*I could move the code written in `setup` to `init` but the problem is that I have more than one designated initializer (for example: UIViewControllers has `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`) and I am lazy about writing code twice.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you reject renaming the methods. It's a simple solution.

Another approach is to use functions instead of methods. Functions are dispatched statically, not dynamically.

For example, in the implementation of `A`:

```
static void setup(A* self)
{
    self.someProperty = /* ... whatever ... */;
}

- (instancetype)init // designated initializer
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        setup(self); // just sets some properties
    }

    return self;
}
```

Likewise for `B`.

In a function, `self` doesn't have any special meaning, so it's just a local variable name. You could use a different one, if you prefer.

Assuming the function is inside the `@implementation`, it has full access to the object, including to private instance variables. So, `setup()` could use `self->_someProperty` instead of `self.someProperty`.

Comment: Thanks! My problem with renaming is that it somehow shows that this approach is not the most beautiful way to setup some properties. That's why I am rather looking for other ideas how to archive this.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple approach? Make `setup` in `B` call `[super setup]` and don't call `setup` in `B`.

Comment: Unfortunately, setup is a private method.

Comment: @Duc By private you probably mean "not declared in header". What about making it visible in an internal category? They you will be able to override it.